# Need help Selecting

Tags: jquery-selectors, show-hide

I have HTML similar to this :

```
<div class="MainForm">
    <form name="FromName">
     <button name="Button1"></button>
     ...
     ...
    </form>
   <Div class="blackBox" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
   <Div class="SubFotm" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
</div>
```

Now I can properly find the trigger for my button click in my script, but I'm not able to target only the closet blackbox to turn it visible.

Currently I'm doing :

```
if (PButtonName=="Fermer") {
$(this).closest("div .ProfileForm").remove(); // Closing Profile Form
}  else if (PButtonName=="plusAdresse") {
alert('In');
      $(this).closest("div .BlackBox").css("visibility","visible");  
}
```

I can get the alert `"In"` to show, but not the BlackBox
If I change the

```
$(this).closest("div .BlackBox").css("visibility","visible");
```

for :

```
 $("div .FormBlackBox").css("visibility","visible");
```

It will show, but will also show all the black box in the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the above HTML, or something similar, I would do it using a reference to the parents.

instead of:

```
$(".MainForm").closest("div .BlackBox").css('visibility','visible');
```

use

```
$(this).parents('.MainForm').children('.BlackBox').css('visibility','visible');
```

This is assuming you have more than one MainForm div and they all have a single child with the BlackBox class.

[here is an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/XbSfJ/)

Comment: I love You!!!!! ( Not really, but you get the idea!!!) that exacly what I needed!

Comment: I am very glad it could help. I find myself often struggling with the right jQuery object to select from. I have fought this exact battle before, that is how I knew.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of what you have done just add styles `display:none;` to your divs and then show them whenever you want.So you can do this as below:

```
<div class="MainForm">
    <form name="FromName">
     <button name="Button1"></button>
     ...
     ...
    </form>

   <div class="blackBox" style="display:none;"></div>
   <div class="SubFotm" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

and then in your script

```
if (PButtonName=="Fermer") 
{
      $(".MainForm").closest("div .ProfileForm").remove(); // Closing Profile Form
}  
else if (PButtonName=="plusAdresse")
 {
     alert('In');
     $(".MainForm").closest("div .BlackBox").show();  
}
```

And I will recommend you using `Switch case` instead of loops at this place.

Comment: Hi, Thank for the switch idea! I'm new to JavaScript, but not to programing so I didn't think of this option. But My Problem is that whiting "$(this).closest("div .BlackBox").show();" is not selecting my black box...

Comment: @DanielBerthiaume Yes..this is what you seem to  be asking in question?